# Iptables killswitch for Wireguard

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, wireguard

I would like to ask for a little help in setting up a killswitch for my VPN.

I am using the following setup on my Pi and I am setting Pi's IP as gateway on my selected client (192.168.2.16). In this way the client traffic is routed trough the VPN.

Everything works great, but I would like to add a killswitch if for some reason connection to VPN goes down, route traffic to a blackhole.

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.111.111.111/32
Table = 43

PostUp = ip rule add from 192.168.2.16 table 43; iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o %i -j MASQUERADE

PostDown = ...


[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 86.xxx.xxx.xxx:51820
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a low priority number to your `PostUp` routing policy rule, like say `143` (and delete it the same way in the `PostDown` script):

```
PostUp = ip rule add from 192.168.2.16 table 43 priority 143; ...
PostDown = ip rule del from 192.168.2.16 table 43 priority 143; ...
```

Rules with a lower priority number are matched first. If you don't set a priority, the OS will set it to a number around `32765`, just below the default rules.

Then add a rule when you start up your Pi (where you do this depends on OS and version) with a higher priority number (but below `32000` or so) that will reject all traffic from `192.168.2.16`:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.2.16 prohibit priority 1043
```

With this in place, when the WireGuard interface is down, the routing engine will match rule `1043` as it routes traffic from `192.168.2.16`, and reject that traffic. When you start up the WireGuard interface with `wg-quick`, it will add rule `143`, which will take precedence, and start routing traffic from `192.168.2.16` through the WireGuard tunnel (via the route set up by `wg-quick` in table `43`). When you shut down the WireGuard interface with `wg-quick` (or reboot the Pi), rule `143` will be removed, and rule `1043` will be matched again.